# mp.pause(); is crashing the application

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio

Trying to put a "pause" button into my application that plays a few sound clips looping.

When I call mp.pause(); all hell breaks loose, I'm totally lost!

Here is the method I'm using..

```
    protected void managerOfSound(String theText) {
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.reset();
        mp.release();
    }

        if (theText.equals(campfire))
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.campfire);
        else if (theText.equals(calmthunder))
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.calmthunderstorm);
        else if (theText.equals(rainthunder))
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rainthunder);
        else if (theText.equals(whalesgulls))
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.whalesandgulls);
        else if (theText.equals(stopplaying))
            mp.pause();

    mp.start();
    mp.setLooping(true);
}
```

And here's a logcat (Meow ^_^)

```
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2f6c648)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setLooping(Native Method)
at com.tags4apps.soothingsounds.MainActivity.managerOfSound(MainActivity.java:83)
at com.tags4apps.soothingsounds.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:34)
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm open to any suggestions right now

edit: What's with the downvotes, I'm 7pm I've been looking for a way to resolve this since 3pm. So downvoting it saying that It's lack of research is kind of unfair..

Comment: Have you tried adding a check like if(mp.isPlaying) mp.pause(). It's a good safety since pause() shouldn't be called otherwise anyway.

Comment: @Broatian originally I had "else if(theText.equals(stopplaying) && mp.isPlaying())" but it didn't make any difference

Comment: Your program logic seems faulty for example, if you enter this code with stopplaying as your argument, then it looks to me like you will reset() and release() the mediaplayer instance, and then, *without creating a new one* try to pause() start() and setLooping() it.  But after you call release() that instance is invalid and must not be used.  Also note that it is no pause() which is directly triggering the crash, but rather setLooping().

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am passing stopplaying into this just to run the if statement to do the mp.pause(). I have tried putting the setLooping(true) before the start(); with no success. Also I have tried putting setLooping(false) in before the pause(), again with not much success.

Comment: I believe your problem is with calling release() before any of these.  I think you have overlooked that your program flow involves doing that first, such that you are then operating on an invalid instance.  Basically you should only be doing that in the cases where you are going to create a new instance.  Likely you should flip your if statements, check for pause first, and if not that *then* release the old one and decide which new one to create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be a **complete** answer, but I'll attempt to address a fairly obvious problem in the current code:

```
protected void managerOfSound(String theText) {
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.reset();
        mp.release();   //from this point on it is illegal 
                        //to operate on the existing mp object
    }
//if you take one of these branches you will get a new mp instance, and be fine
    if (theText.equals(campfire))
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.campfire); 
   else if (theText.equals(calmthunder))
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.calmthunderstorm);
    else if (theText.equals(rainthunder))
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rainthunder);
    else if (theText.equals(whalesgulls))
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.whalesandgulls);
//but if you take this branch, you will be illegally operating on a released instance
    else if (theText.equals(stopplaying))
        mp.pause();

    mp.start();
    mp.setLooping(true);
}
```

---

Instead, do something like this:

```
protected void managerOfSound(String theText) {
    if (theText.equals(stopplaying)) {
        if (mp != null) mp.pause();

    } else {  //we are not pausing
        if (mp != null) {  //lets release any old one
            mp.reset();
            mp.release();   
        }
        //and then get an appropriate new instance
        if (theText.equals(campfire))
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.campfire); 
        else if (theText.equals(calmthunder))
             mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.calmthunderstorm);
        else if (theText.equals(rainthunder))
             mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rainthunder);
        else if (theText.equals(whalesgulls))
             mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.whalesandgulls);
        //Note this will still fail if there is some OTHER possibility
        mp.start();
        mp.setLooping(true);
      } 
}
```

Comment: You my friend, are what legends are made of! This worked flawlessly, I can see exactly where I went wrong now so I cannot thank you enough!

Comment: Glad it helped.  For the record, I'm not sure it's robust yet.  You might think about ways to better group the "will be creating a new one and starting it" vs "will be modifying an existing one" vs "that shouldn't happen" cases even more appropriately.

Comment: Understandably there is always room to improve everything, but just being able to play those sound effects and actually have a single button to stop the sound is exactly what I have been trying to work toward this evening. As it stands, it works :) If any more issues do crop up I will be looking at it from there. Once again, thankyou..